# How can I make `target_link_libraries` dependencies transitive from OBJECT libraries in cmake?

Tags: cmake

If I specify a dependency chain of `OBJECT` libraries in CMake, only the `target_link_libraries` dependencies of the very last one is used in the target executable.

Minimal Example:

`main` depends on `objB`, which depends on `objA`.
Both `objA` and `objB` are `OBJECT` libraries in CMake.

I would expect `main` to link with both object files. It doesn't.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)
project(transitive-object-library-link-issue VERSION 1.0.0 LANGUAGES C)

add_library(objA OBJECT a.c)

add_library(objB OBJECT b.c)
target_link_libraries(objB PUBLIC objA)

# Should link with 'a.o', since 'objA' is "linked" by 'objB'
add_executable(main main.c)
target_link_libraries(main objB)
```

Note: A working set of files are available at https://github.com/scraimer/cmake-transitive-object-library-link-issue

If I change `objA` to a non-`OBJECT` library, the problem is eliminated by getting rid of the chain of `OBJECT` library dependencies. In other words, change the line

```
add_library(objA OBJECT a.c)
```

To be:

```
add_library(objA a.c)
```

So it's something specific to `OBJECT` libraries. How should I be specifying the dependencies to make `main` link with `objA`? (Without having to specify `objA` in every executable target that uses `objB`)

Comment: Both `objA` and `objA` are OBJECT libraries in CMake. 
Do you means Both `objA` and `objB` are OBJECT libraries in CMake.

Comment: @ManthanTilva Fixed. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This stems from another issue with `OBJECT` libraries: duplication of object code. As Brad King [explains](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/18090#note_423521):

> we'd need to be careful to de-duplicate use of [example item's] object files

If transitive propagation was the default, you could accidentally cause the linker to try linking multiple copies of the same code, thus dooming your project to be non-compilable by CMake.

That is a good enough reason not to allow transitive dependencies of `OBJECT` libraries. It's tricky, so best avoided. So much so that it's mentioned as a Good Practice in his excellent book "[Professional CMake: A Practical Guide](https://crascit.com/professional-cmake/)":

> If a target uses something from a library, it should always link directly to that library. Even if the
>   library is already a link dependency of something else the target links to, do not rely on an indirect
>   link dependency for something a target uses directly.

He also added [in another issue](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/18682#note_491201):

> he transitive nature of object libraries is not the same as regular libraries. The [build-system](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html#object-libraries) manual words it like this:
>
> > The link (or archiving) step of those other targets will use the object files from object libraries that are directly linked.
>
> The key part of that is the "directly linked". In your example, `main` gets the objects from `b` because it links directly to `b`, but because it does not link directly to `a`, it does not get `a`'s objects, even though `b` links to `a`.
>   The reason for this is related to problems where deep transivity can result in object files being added multiple times, which will cause an error. This particular aspect has come up a few times in the issue tracker, but I don't have the issue numbers at hand (you can probably search for them and track down the various discussions).

So the solution seems to be to avoid relying on `target_link_library` for `OBJECT` libraries. There are two ways: First is to simply not use `OBJECT` libraries. Second is to explicitly specify objects to link in the hierarchy, as [proposed](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/18682#note_495301) by Hiroshi Miura:

```
add_library(a OBJECT a.c)
add_library(b OBJECT b.c)
target_sources(b PUBLIC $<TARGET_OBJECTS:a>)

add_executable(main main.c)
target_sources(main PRIVATE $<TARGET_OBJECTS:b>)
```

This is explicit, but doesn't even solve the problem I have! I suspect this also might run into duplication issues due to diamond patterns, but I haven't tested that.

Maybe over the next few months I'll figure out a better solution using generator expressions based on the LINK_LIBRARIES property of the `objA`. Not sure how to do that, though.

Answer (score 6):

[Object library](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_library.html#object-libraries) targets are not real libraries, they are simply a collection of objects, but they are not really linked together until they are used to build a real target like an executable or shared/static library. Citing the linked documentation:

```
add_library(<name> OBJECT <src>...)
```

> Creates an Object Library. An object library compiles source files but does   not archive or link their object files into a library.

In despite of that, [you can apply](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html#linking-object-libraries) a `target_link_library()` command to an object library, but only to specify dependencies of their sources on other libraries. The linked documentation explains your problem:

> The object library’s usage requirements are propagated transitively [...], but its object files are not.
>
> Object Libraries may “link” to other object libraries to get usage requirements, but since they do not have a link step nothing is done with their object files.

So, the transitive propagation affects only to compile definitions and dependencies of other real libraries, not the objects themselves.

Comment: I would have expected `target_link_library` to also be a "object library’s usage requirement", and therefore to be "propagated transitively".

Comment: I agree, it's awkward to say the least. Given that this CMake Object Libraries feature seems to replace libtool convenience libraries, it should also provide this convenience.

Answer (score 3):

One solution is to define an INTERFACE library for each OBJECT library. Dependencies of interface libraries are transitive.

```
# Defines an object library named ${T}_obj,
# interface library named ${T} linked to it,
# and sets ${varname} to ${T}_obj.
macro(add_object varname T)
  add_library(${T}_obj OBJECT ${ARGN})
  add_library(${T} INTERFACE)
  target_link_libraries(${T} INTERFACE ${T}_obj $<TARGET_OBJECTS:${T}_obj>)
  set(${varname} ${T}_obj)
endmacro(add_object)
```

Usage

```
add_object(T a a.c) 

add_object(T b b.c) # sets T to b_obj
target_link_libraries(${T} a)
```

Comment: Sigh, that this is needed is crazy.